# print lines with specific words

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, scripting

Say I have two files (`file1.txt` & `file2.txt`).

`file1.txt`: (contains only list of words, one per line)

```
Car
Ricky
```

`file2.txt`: (contains lines (phrases) using words from `file1.txt` and more)

```
he has a Car
there is no food
I have a book
road is straight
Ricky is a good student
```

The output should be:

```
he has a Car
Ricky is a good student
```

Comment: Contrary to common belief, this is not a homework help site. If you have tried to solve the problem at hand but you ran into a problem, please show what you have done and people will help you solve the problem. But do not expect someone to do your work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `grep` supports the `-w` option:

```
grep -wFf file1.txt file2.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, it sounds like you want to grab lines from file2.txt that contain words from file1.txt

This can easily be achieved by using `grep` and a `for` loop.

Basically, you can cat file1.txt and then feed that into a grep command.

`for i in $(cat file1.txt); do grep $i file2.txt; done`